# Где тут сказуемое: "Прозрачные здания подобны тонким вышивкам из белого шелка"?

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор

*Песок блестит на солнце тёплым, жёлтым блеском, и на его бархате прозрачные здания подобны тонким вышивкам из белого шелка.*

Тут сказуемое — *подобны тонким вышивкам из белого шелка?*
Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Тут сказуемое, наверное,- это " подобны тонким вышивкам из белого
>   шелка".

Сказуемое: ***подобны вышивкам***.

*Тонким, из шёлка, белого* -- определения.

Comment: Хотел еще спросить про сказуемое. В предложение: " мыло серо, зато моет бело". Серо и бело - сказуемые?

Comment: _Серо_ -- сказуемое, _бело_ -- обстоятельство.